# jquery ui - What class can I use to get the border color?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a 1px border around a div. I have themeswitcher attached to the same div. When the user changes the theme I want my 1px border to change color according to the new theme. It's okay if the new themes border is a little bigger.

ui-border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

depending on what look your going for you can either use `ui-widget-content` or `ui-state-default`

good luck, hope this helps -ck

Comment: http://www.seanmchugh.info/player.htm - the border around the player. On second thought maybe it is always good black.

Comment: was already using widget-content. eventually gave up and stuck with black. thx